Java generics with supplier functions does no type checks
My problem is that i want to compare two objects with a generic method with a
function in which i can error-handle any Exceptions.
In the code example i don't understand why this code will compile. Object.equals lets me
compare any Objects, but the functions is expected to limit the input space.
Does anybody see the problem here?
public class EqualsMain {
    public static <T> boolean myEquals(T expected, Supplier<T> actual) {
        try {
            T actualValue = actual.get();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // do some error handling
        }
        return expected.equals(actual.get());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // will compile, even though types don't match
        System.out.println(myEquals(true, () -> ""));
    }
}


Prolem is; it is working... Best case the compiler would complain at throwing in a boolean and a supplier which returns String (see main() method), you see what i mean.

why shouldn't it work? the compiler infers the (best) type for T, in this case Object (and maybe a bit more), so true get wrapped in a Boolean and the supplier will supply type Object (and "" is a valid Object)

("a bit more" could also be Serializable)

There is no way to prevent this behavior, because this compiles just fine if T is Object.  Both a boolean and a String can be upcast to Object without any problems.  There's no way to automatically enforce that these types don't match.  (There's a reason Objects.equals works the way it does.)
You can force it not to compile by writing EqualsMain.<Boolean>myEquals, but that's not really addressing the point.

Ok besides from the "equals" functionality, i want a function with a specified generic to return the same type i put in. Maybe i will have to implement all the types like in Assertations.assertWhatever() implementations...

You could do something like the following (although this may not cover all the corner cases (e.g. using subclassing, etc).
public static <T> boolean myEquals(T expected, Supplier<T> actual) {
    if (expected.getClass().equals(actual.get().getClass())) {
        return expected.equals(actual.get());
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Mixed types passed");
}


Yes, this also would fix the issue of class inequality, but also only at runtime.
